# How to disable mouse scroll trigger in fullpage.js only

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

In fullpage.js core functions

How to customize such that when set option autoScrolling: true.

1.only disable mouse scroll behavior trigger in section scrolling control.

2.other keyboard scroll triggers still working. (such as keyup keydown end home etc)

here is the fullpage.js code from git:
      https://github.com/ajgagnon/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.js

Explaination: 
why need to disable mouse scroll sometimes. Because there are scroll sensitivity issues in fullpage.js when "scrollOverflow: true". However, if you totally disabled the 
"autoScrolling: true" option, by default keyboard trigger still allow to scroll up down left right.   ( "keyboardScrolling: true" by default; )

**However,** I discovered when  "scrollOverflow: false" option together with "keyboardScrolling: true", the content will shake instantly the moment you press down the arrow keys. don't know how to fix, so it's my purpose to keep scrollOverflow:true while disable mouse scroll only. then will be no issue. )

Answer (score 31):

How about:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        ...
    });

    $.fn.fullpage.setMouseWheelScrolling(false);
    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

> However, if you totally disabled the "autoScrolling: true" option, by
>   default keyboard trigger still allow to scroll up down left right. (
>   "keyboardScrolling: true" by defa

Not anymore since fullPage.js 2.4.9. `autoScrolling:false` will disable the auto scroll with keyboard as well.

Answer (score 2):

Alvaro, to disable keyboard you should use: `keyboardScrolling: false`

Comment: That option probably didn't exist when the question was asked. In any case, I was clarifying part of his comments.

Comment: Funny answer - telling the owner how to use his plugin :D